# How to insert a text with single quots to sqlite db in android?

Tags: android, string, sqlite

I am facing an issue in inserting an issue in inserting a text with single quotes in sqlite db in android. it is returning the following error.

```
06-21 15:21:55.644: E/AndroidRuntime(16328): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
"re": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from tbl_chatHistory where 
chat_date = '1.403344315631E12' and chat_time = '1.403344315635E12' and chat_text = 
'you're'
```

Please help.

******************** EDITED *****************************

```
public boolean checkChatExists(String date, String time, String chat) {
    boolean result = false;
    String selectQuery = "select * from tbl_chatHistory where chat_date = '"+date+"'
    and chat_time = '"+time+"' and chat_text = '"+chat+"'";
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result = true;
    } else {
    result = false;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Post your code... and consider using `?` parametrized queries instead of injection-prone raw SQL. Floating point numbers as date/time don't seem to be a good idea either.

Comment: @laalto Edited the question with code. Please help.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have the problem. `ContentValues`-based methods already use parametrized queries automaticaly. The problem is in a `select`, not `insert`.

Comment: @laalto Sorry. By mistake I copied the insert method. Now I have edited the question with the select method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL string literals you can escape `'` as `''`.

It however better to use parametrized queries. Replace the string literals with `?` and provide the values in the `bindArgs` array. For example:

```
String selectQuery = "select * from tbl_chatHistory where chat_date = ? and chat_time = ? and chat_text = ?";
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { date, time, chat });
```

Comment: Haha. I was just about to add the same. So, Here's goes an upvote!

Answer (score -1):

Use ` instead of '. The problem is that the second ' is recognised as the end of the text.